# Difference in two for nested loops.(C++)

Tags: c++, nested-loops

I tried to solve the following problem:

Let x,y,z be integers in the domain [-5,5]. Display the number of solutions (x,y,z) that satisfy 3*x+y^3-z^2=0. My initial solution was this:

```
int main() {
    int x=-6;
    int y=-6;
    int z=-6;
    int p=0;
    for(int i=-5; i<6; i++)
    {
        x++;
        for (int j=-5; j<6; j++)
        {
            y++;
            for(int k=-5; k<6; k++)
            {
                z++;
                if(3*x +y*y*y -z*z==0)
                    p++;          
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout<< p ;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the correct solution:

```
 int main() {
        int x=-5;
        int y=-5;
        int z=-5;
        int p=0;
        for( x=-5; x<=5; x++)
           for (y=-5; y<=5; y++)
               for( z=-5; z<=5; z++)
                   if(3*x +y*y*y -z*z==0)
                       p++;

        std::cout<< p;
        return 0;
}
```

Why are these two different and what did I do wrong in the first one?

Comment: Let x,y,z be integers in the domain [-5,5], Do you need one more number with [-5,5] to specify 3-dimension?

Comment: The correct solution is simpler (even simpler is `for(int x=-5; x<=5; x++) ...` keeping variables at the least local scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the incorrect code, the variables y and z are not reset to the beginning of their range at the begining of the loop.

An even shorter correct exemple would be:

```
int main()
{
    int p = 0;
    for( int x=-5; x<=5; ++x )
       for( int y=-5; y<=5; ++y )
           for( z=-5; z<=5; ++z)
               if( 3*x + y*y*y - z*z == 0 )
                   ++p;
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The variable initializations can be put directly into the loops.
As they are trivial variables there is no performance penalty.

Answer (score 3):

In the "correct" solution, `y` begins again from `-5` for each new value of `x`. In your version, `y` carries on incrementing from its previous value, so the second iteration covers `[5,15]`, the third `[15,25]`, and so on.

The weird extra variable `j` covers the range you want `y` to cover each time, but `y` itself does not.

Comment: The values of `z` suffer from the same problem.

Comment: @RSahu: Indeed, I refrained from stating the obvious.

Comment: I gathered as much. That was hopefully useful to the OP.